# Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class

Tags: java, redis

When I want to deserilize the ArticleZSet list that fetched from redis, shows error like this:

```
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class misc.model.auth.article.ArticleZSet
 at [Source: (byte[])"3231787"; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class misc.model.auth.article.ArticleZSet
 at [Source: (byte[])"3231787"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:75) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserializeValues(SerializationUtils.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:62) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeValues(AbstractOperations.java:224) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultZSetOperations.reverseRangeByScore(DefaultZSetOperations.java:346) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.article.ArticleService.getArticleImpl(ArticleService.java:174) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.article.ArticleService.pageByCache(ArticleService.java:112) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.article.ArticleController.newStories(ArticleController.java:102) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.article.ArticleController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$660ab6b6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.
```

this is the code that defined the deserilize process:

```
@Bean(name = "redisZSetTemplate")
    RedisTemplate<String, ArticleZSet> redisTemplateZSet(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, ArticleZSet> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(ArticleZSet.class);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        serializer.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        template.setValueSerializer(serializer);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(serializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(serializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem?